# How can I approximate method overloading?

Tags: overloading, rust

I am modeling an API where method overloading would be a good fit. My naïve attempt failed:

```
// fn attempt_1(_x: i32) {}
// fn attempt_1(_x: f32) {}
// Error: duplicate definition of value `attempt_1`
```

I then added an enum and worked through to:

```
enum IntOrFloat {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32),
}

fn attempt_2(_x: IntOrFloat) {}

fn main() {
    let i: i32 = 1;
    let f: f32 = 3.0;

    // Can't pass the value directly
    // attempt_2(i);
    // attempt_2(f);
    // Error: mismatched types: expected enum `IntOrFloat`

    attempt_2(IntOrFloat::Int(i));
    attempt_2(IntOrFloat::Float(f));
    // Ugly that the caller has to explicitly wrap the parameter
}
```

Doing some quick searches, I've [found](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2012-April/001649.html) [some](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1838) [references](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/wiki/Rust-for-CXX-programmers#function-overloading) that talk about overloading, and all of them seem to end in "we aren't going to allow this, but give traits a try". So I tried:

```
enum IntOrFloat {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32),
}

trait IntOrFloatTrait {
    fn to_int_or_float(&self) -> IntOrFloat;
}

impl IntOrFloatTrait for i32 {
    fn to_int_or_float(&self) -> IntOrFloat {
        IntOrFloat::Int(*self)
    }
}

impl IntOrFloatTrait for f32 {
    fn to_int_or_float(&self) -> IntOrFloat {
        IntOrFloat::Float(*self)
    }
}

fn attempt_3(_x: &dyn IntOrFloatTrait) {}

fn main() {
    let i: i32 = 1;
    let f: f32 = 3.0;

    attempt_3(&i);
    attempt_3(&f);
    // Better, but the caller still has to explicitly take the reference
}
```

Is this the closest I can get to method overloading? Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is, and you almost got it already. Traits are the way to go, but you don't need trait objects, use generics:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum IntOrFloat {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32),
}

trait IntOrFloatTrait {
    fn to_int_or_float(&self) -> IntOrFloat;
}

impl IntOrFloatTrait for i32 {
    fn to_int_or_float(&self) -> IntOrFloat {
        IntOrFloat::Int(*self)
    }
}

impl IntOrFloatTrait for f32 {
    fn to_int_or_float(&self) -> IntOrFloat {
        IntOrFloat::Float(*self)
    }
}

fn attempt_4<T: IntOrFloatTrait>(x: T) {
    let v = x.to_int_or_float();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    let i: i32 = 1;
    let f: f32 = 3.0;

    attempt_4(i);
    attempt_4(f);
}
```

See it working [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3ad80be2a36eeddc0429&version=stable).

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way that drops the `enum`. It's an iteration on Vladimir's answer.

```rust
trait Tr {
  fn go(&self) -> ();
}

impl Tr for i32 {
  fn go(&self) {
    println!("i32")
  }
}

impl Tr for f32 {
  fn go(&self) {
    println!("f32")
  }
}

fn attempt_1<T: Tr>(t: T) {
  t.go()
}

fn main() {
  attempt_1(1 as i32);
  attempt_1(1 as f32);
}
```

Comment: Would it be more idiomatic to implement `attempt` as a trait method, removing the top-level function? (I understand that wouldn't directly answer the OP's question)

Comment: @MaxHeiber maybe. I don't know enough rust to say

Answer (score 5):

**Function Overloading is Possible!!!** *(well, sorta...)*

This [Rust Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7d82b120641d0074577a14e75c60680) has more a more detailed example, and shows usage of a struct variant, which may be better for documentation on the parameters.

For more serious flexible overloading where you want to have sets of any number of parameters of any sort of type, you can take advantage of the `From<T>` trait for conversion of a tuple to enum variants, and have a generic function that converts tuples passed into it to the enum type.

So code like this is possible:

```
fn main() {
    let f = Foo { };
    f.do_something(3.14);               // One f32.
    f.do_something((1, 2));             // Two i32's...
    f.do_something(("Yay!", 42, 3.14)); // A str, i32, and f64 !!
}
```

First, define the different sets of parameter combinations as an enum:

```
// The variants should consist of unambiguous sets of types.
enum FooParam {
    Bar(i32, i32),
    Baz(f32),
    Qux(&'static str, i32, f64),
}
```

Now, the conversion code; a macro can be written to do the tedious `From<T>` implementations, but here's what it could produce:

```
impl From<(i32, i32)> for FooParam {
    fn from(p: (i32, i32)) -> Self {
        FooParam::Bar(p.0, p.1)
    }
}
impl From<f32> for FooParam {
    fn from(p: f32) -> Self {
        FooParam::Baz(p)
    }
}
impl From<(&'static str, i32, f64)> for FooParam {
    fn from(p: (&'static str, i32, f64)) -> Self {
        FooParam::Qux(p.0, p.1, p.2)
    }
}
```

And then finally, implement the struct with generic method:

```
struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    fn do_something<T: Into<FooParam>>(&self, t: T) {
        use FooParam::*;
        let fp = t.into();
        match fp {
            Bar(a, b)    => print!("Bar: {:?}, {:?}\n", a, b),
            Baz(a)       => print!("Baz: {:?}\n", a),
            Qux(a, b, c) => {
                print!("Qux: {:?}, {:?}, {:?}\n", a, b, c)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The trait bound on `T` needs to be specified.

Also, the variants need to be composed of combinations of types that the compiler wouldn't find ambiguous - which is an expectation for overloaded methods in other languages as well (Java/C++).

This approach has possibilities... it would be awesome if there's a decorator available - or one were written that did the `From<T>` implementations automatically when applied to an enum. Something like this:

```
// THIS DOESN'T EXIST - so don't expect the following to work.
// This is just an example of a macro that could be written to
// help in using the above approach to function overloading.

#[derive(ParameterOverloads)]
enum FooParam {
    Bar(i32, i32),
    Baz(f32),
    Qux(&'static str, i32, f64),
}

// If this were written, it could eliminate the tedious
// implementations of From<...>.
```

Answer (score 3):

#### The Builder

Another approach that addresses the case where you have multiple optional parameters to an action or configuration is the [builder pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/ownership/builders.html). The examples below deviate somewhat from the recommendations in the link. Typically, there's a separate builder class/struct which finalizes the configuration and returns the configured object when a final method is invoked.

One of the most relevant situations this can apply to is where you want a constructor that takes a variable number of optional arguments - since Rust doesn't have built-in overloading, we can't have multiple versions of `___::new()`. But we can get a similar effect using a chain of methods that return `self`. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2af184b5d80e015ad0d42b7f146ebd58).

```rust
fn main() {
    // Create.
    let mut bb = BattleBot::new("Berzerker".into());
    
    // Configure.
    bb.flame_thrower(true)
      .locomotion(TractorTreads)
      .power_source(Uranium);
    
    println!("{:#?}", bb);
}
```

Each of the configuration methods has a signature similar to:

```rust
    fn power_source(&mut self, ps: PowerSource) -> &mut Self {
        self.power_source = ps;
        self
    }
```

These methods could also be written to consume `self` and return non-reference copies or clones of `self`.

This approach can also be applied to actions. For instance, we could have a `Command` object that can be tuned with chained methods, which then performs the command when `.exec()` is invoked.

Applying this same idea to an "overloaded" method that we want to take a variable number of parameters, we modify our expectations a bit and have the method take an object that can be configured with the builder pattern.

```rust
    let mut params = DrawParams::new();

    graphics.draw_obj(params.model_path("./planes/X15.m3d")
                            .skin("./skins/x15.sk")
                            .location(23.64, 77.43, 88.89)
                            .rotate_x(25.03)
                            .effect(MotionBlur));
```

Alternatively, we could decide on having a `GraphicsObject` struct that has several config tuning methods, then performs the drawing when `.draw()` is invoked.