# Can a function accept an argument of type Option or &str or String?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a fast, flexible and convenient API that accepts an optional string parameter. I wish the user to be able to pass:

- `None`
- `"foo"`
- `"foo".to_string()`
- `Some("foo")` (equivalent to `"foo"`)
- `Some("foo".to_string())` (equivalent to `"foo".to_string()`)

As far as I know, the best solution to handle `"foo"` or `"foo".to_string()` is `Into<Cow<'a, str>>`. On the other hand, the best solution to handle `"foo"` or `Some("foo")` is `Into<Option<&'a str>>`.

Thus I tried with this but it doesn't compile:

```
fn foo<'a, T, O>(_bar: O)
where
    T: Into<Cow<'a, str>>,
    O: Into<Option<T>>,
```

```
foo(Some("aaa"));
```

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: std::convert::Into<std::borrow::Cow<'_, str>>`
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     foo(Some("aaa"));
   |     ^^^
   |
note: required by `foo`
  --> src/main.rs:3:1
   |
3  | / fn foo<'a, T, O>(_bar: O)
4  | | where
5  | |     T: Into<Cow<'a, str>>,
6  | |     O: Into<Option<T>>,
7  | | {}
   | |__^
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=06b2d72871ac81b705f2b8f2ca94ffe7&version=stable)

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: Use trait + generic. I am pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: I get: _"error: the trait bound `Cow<'_, str>: From<Option<&str>>` is not satisfied"_. If I remove the `Cow` constraint then it all works.

Comment: @Boiethios could you please give some more details?

Comment: *the best solution to handle `"foo"` or `"foo".to_string()` is `Into<Cow<'a, str>>`* — I don't know that I agree with that at all. Like most everything in programming, it depends.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the function signature is valid. Even if you pass some concrete type for `O`, there isn't necessarily a unique `T` that corresponds, is there?

Comment: @PeterHall or "worse", there might be *multiple* types (or paths) that do correspond. Then the code to run would be ambiguous.

Comment: @synek317 To emulate function overloading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25265605/4498831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I approximate method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265527/how-can-i-approximate-method-overloading)

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=96a8296f5ed0272257bb8ba6061ece3f&version=stable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot create a function like this and still have it be ergonomically used. The problem is that there can be zero, one, or multiple potential paths through the generic types:

```
            +-----------+
            |           |
  +---------> Option<B> +----------------------+
  |         |           |                      |
+-+-+       +-----------+          +-----------v----------+
|   |                              |                      |
| A |                              | Option<Cow<'a, str>> |
|   |                              |                      |
+-+-+       +-----------+          +-----------^----------+
  |         |           |                      |
  +---------> Option<C> +----------------------+
            |           |
            +-----------+
```

That's why you are getting the error you are: It's unclear what the concrete type of `T` should be, thus the caller would have to provide it to the compiler. Here I use the *turbofish*:

```
foo::<&str, _>(Some("aaa"));
foo::<String, _>(Some("aaa".to_string()));
foo::<&str, Option<&str>>(None);
```

I'd suggest re-evaluating your API design. Possible directions include:

1. Creating a custom struct and implementing `From` for specific concrete types (e.g. `&str`, `Option<String>`, etc.). Passing `None` will still have the problem because it's unclear what type of `None` it is: an `Option<&str>` or `Option<String>`?

   ```
   use std::borrow::Cow;

   fn foo<'a, C>(_bar: C)
   where
       C: Into<Config<'a>>,
   {
   }

   struct Config<'a>(Option<Cow<'a, str>>);

   impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Config<'a> {
       fn from(other: &'a str) -> Config<'a> {
           Config(Some(other.into()))
       }
   }

   impl From<String> for Config<'static> {
       fn from(other: String) -> Config<'static> {
           Config(Some(other.into()))
       }
   }

   impl<'a> From<Option<&'a str>> for Config<'a> {
       fn from(other: Option<&'a str>) -> Config<'a> {
           Config(other.map(Into::into))
       }
   }

   impl From<Option<String>> for Config<'static> {
       fn from(other: Option<String>) -> Config<'static> {
           Config(other.map(Into::into))
       }
   }

   fn main() {
       foo("aaa");
       foo("aaa".to_string());

       foo(Some("aaa"));
       foo(Some("aaa".to_string()));
       foo(None::<&str>);
   }
   ```
2. Switch to a builder pattern — my preferred direction:

   ```
   use std::borrow::Cow;

   #[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
   struct Foo<'a> {
       name: Option<Cow<'a, str>>,
   }

   impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
       fn new() -> Self {
           Self::default()
       }

       fn name<S>(mut self, name: S) -> Self
       where
           S: Into<Cow<'a, str>>,
       {
           self.name = Some(name.into());
           self
       }

       fn go(self) {
           println!("The name is {:?}", self.name)
       }
   }

   fn main() {
       Foo::new().go();
       Foo::new().name("aaa").go();
       Foo::new().name("aaa".to_string()).go();
   }
   ```

   Note that this removes the need for the caller to specify `Some` at all; using the `name` function implies presence. You could make a `without_name` function to set it back to `None` if needed.

See also:

- [Pass None into a function that accepts Option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886379/155423)
- [Create a generic struct with Option<T> without specifying T when instantiating with None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42141129/155423)