# How to implement generics in rust when the generic parameter has multiple datatypes?

Tags: generics, rust

I am newbie to Rust.

I am trying to implement a generic function in rust, but I am facing problems with it. I tried so many examples from google to get the solution, but nothing worked. Please help me.

Here in the code below, I want to implement `add` function for `Point` which can take either `i32` or another `Point`.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
    let mut point = Point::new(1,1);
    point.add::<i32>(&1);
    point.add::<Point>(&point);
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point {x, y}
    }

    /**
    Pseudocode as i don't know how to write this in rust
    pub fn add<T: Sized || Point>(&mut self, value: &T) {
            if (T is i32) {
                self.x += = value;
                self.y += value;
            } else (T is Point) {
                self.x += value.x;
                self.y += value.y;
            }
        
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Have you considered implementing [From](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I approximate method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265527/how-can-i-approximate-method-overloading)

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I tried it, but after implementing `From` for `i32`, I got error while calling `point.add::<Point>(&point);`

Comment: @E_net4isbeingtargeted, the link you suggested is implementing `go` method for both `i32` and `f32`, but here i want to implement only for `Point`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a trait. Since `Point` is `Copy`, there's also no need to use references:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point { x, y }
    }
}

trait AddToPoint<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, value: T);
}

impl AddToPoint<i32> for Point {
    fn add(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.x += value;
        self.y += value;
    }
}

impl AddToPoint<Point> for Point {
    fn add(&mut self, value: Point) {
        self.x += value.x;
        self.y += value.y;
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
    let mut point = Point::new(1,1);
    point.add(1);
    point.add(point);
}
```

Another possibility is to use operator overloading, by implementing the trait `std::ops::AddAssign`. Then you can use the `+=` operator to add values to points:

```
use std::ops::AddAssign;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point { x, y }
    }
}

impl AddAssign<i32> for Point {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.x += value;
        self.y += value;
    }
}

impl AddAssign<Point> for Point {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, value: Point) {
        self.x += value.x;
        self.y += value.y;
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
    let mut point = Point::new(1,1);
    point += 1;
    point += point;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example side by side normal function and generic function.
struct Val {
val: f64,
}

```
struct GenVal<T> {
    gen_val: T,
}

// impl of Val
impl Val {
    fn value(&self) -> &f64 {
        &self.val
    }
}

// impl of GenVal for a generic type `T`
impl<T> GenVal<T> {
    fn value(&self) -> &T {
        &self.gen_val
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Val { val: 3.0 };
    let y = GenVal { gen_val: 3i32 };

    println!("{}, {}", x.value(), y.value());
}
```

Comment: The question is asking for the moral equivalent of function overloading, i.e. a function `add` that can be called either with an `i32` or another `Point`.