# How do I make a generic selection of generic functions with same function definition but different T?

Tags: rust

In my simplified example I have an algorithm that takes two parameters `t: T` and `transform_fn: fn(&str) -> T` `where T: TransformRes` and `trait TransformRes: 'static + Eq + Send {}`

Stripped down to a minimum, usage works successfully as below:

```rust
struct TransformParameter<T: TransformRes> {
    compare: T,
    transform_fn: fn(&str) -> T,
}

// TransformParameter works for all types, that implement `Eq`
let t = TransformParameter { compare: transform_usize("5"), transform_fn: transform_usize };
assert_eq!(t.compare, (t.transform_fn)("5"));
let t = TransformParameter { compare: transform_identity("5"), transform_fn: transform_identity };
assert_eq!(t.compare, (t.transform_fn)("5"));
```

I want to enable a dynamic selection, like so

```rust
fn select_transform_fn<T: TransformRes>() -> fn(&str) -> T {
    let cond = false;
    if cond {
        transform_usize
    } else {
        transform_identity
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile of course and I understand why. Unfortunately, I can't think of a solution that enables me a dynamic selection of the transformation algorithm that preserves me the ability to pass generic functions to my struct `TransformParameter`.
How can I combine the API that I want with the ability for a dynamic selection of a generic function?

Full code (on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3907f6caa8e067a8b762d08bf1cb3885)):

```rust
// Result type of transformation functions.
trait TransformRes: 'static + Eq + Send {}
impl<T> TransformRes for T where T: 'static + Eq + Send {}

struct TransformParameter<T: TransformRes> {
    compare: T,
    transform_fn: fn(&str) -> T,
}

// Generic Transform Function 1
fn transform_usize(foo: &str) -> usize {
    foo.parse::<usize>().unwrap()
}

// Generic Transform Function 2
fn transform_identity(foo: &str) -> String {
    String::from(foo)
}

fn main() {
    // generic functions: work
    let t = TransformParameter { compare: transform_usize("5"), transform_fn: transform_usize };
    assert_eq!(t.compare, (t.transform_fn)("5"));
    let t = TransformParameter { compare: transform_identity("5"), transform_fn: transform_identity };
    assert_eq!(t.compare, (t.transform_fn)("5"));

    // generic function selection: doesn't compile.. how to do that?
    let foo = select_transform_fn();
    foo("foo")
}

fn select_transform_fn<T: TransformRes>() -> fn(&str) -> T {
    let cond = false;
    if cond {
        transform_usize
    } else {
        transform_identity
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do something like `execute_transform_fn` instead, selecting and transforming together.

Comment: Could you do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70791812/17312805 and have a `Transformable` trait which you implement for different types (`usize` and identity and so forth)?